# How to subclass from a dynamic WTForm?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I need a form that has a dynamically created part and a static part to it. So I'm thinking of subclassing ... but can't figure out how this would work with a dynamically created form.
I am creating my dynamic form in this way:

**from views.py**

```
def create_legumes_form_class(legumes):
form_fields={}    
for legume in legumes:
    field_id = 's_{}'.format(legume.id)
    form_fields[field_id] = IntegerField(default=0 , validators = [InputRequired()])
return type('OrderForm', (Form,), form_fields)
```

Then instantiating the form in my view function :

```
legumes = Legumes.query.filter_by(disponible = True).all()
OrderForm = create_legumes_form_class(legumes)
form = OrderForm()
```

But to this OrderForm(), I need to add a couple BooleanField(s) that will always be the same (ie. not dynamically created from the Query).

So I am trying to add a (static) form in my **forms.py** and instantiate it like this in the view function:

```
form=OrderForm(StaticForm)
```

But I'm getting

```
    TypeError: formdata should be a multidict-type wrapper that supports the 'getlist' method
```

And I don't know where to take it from here !
What am I doing wrong/not doing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass another class to the `OrderForm` constructor and have it subclass that class. You can, however, provide it when you call `type`.

```
return type('OrderForm', (Form, StaticForm), form_fields)
```

If `StaticForm` subclasses `Form` this can be further simplified.

```
return type('OrderForm', (StaticForm,), form_fields)
```

Comment: Thank you very much mate ! Makes some things that much clearer in my head !